# Java Server Page Not Being Interpreted

Tags: jsp

I am new to JSP.  I have installed Tomcat 7 on my win8 machine  When I double click on index.jsp using the file explorer a browser tab opens and displays the entire file as html.  It is as if tomcat isnt interpreting the page.

the url in the address bar is - file:///C:/Users/Jim/workspace/Jsp/WebContent/Index.jsp

what appears in the browser window is:

Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>

index.jsp contains:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>
</body>
</html>
```

Using netstat and task manager i can see tomcat is using port 8009.  using task manager i can see that tomcat service is running.

When i installed tommcat the page showing that tomcat was up and running displayed correctly.

I created an eclipse project (using luna).  When i "run" the jsp page a new tab opens in eclipse and it correctly displays the jsp (the [page displays the proper date and time stamp)

In the tab address bar in eclipse it displays the file path as:

```
http://localhost:8080/Jsp/Index.jsp
```

When the path specifed uses localhost the page displays correctly:

```
Today's date: Jan 11, 2015 5:06:15 PM
```

and when the path doesn't use localhost the page does not display correctly:

```
Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>
```

I have looked for hours on the web and on stackoverflow.  I dont understand the problem so apparently i cant search for help using the correct keywords.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Have you **deployed** your application to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

> When I double click on index.jsp using the file explorer a browser tab opens and displays the entire file as html.

Correct. You have to use `http://` to get the Java webserver to run the JSP. You're viewing the local source code when use the `file:///C:/Users/Jim/workspace/Jsp/WebContent/Index.jsp` address. The local file system is not hosted by your `eclipse` based web container (the local file system couldn't work *without* a web server otherwise).

```
http://localhost:8080/Jsp/Index.jsp
```

or

```
http://<my_ip_address>:8080/Jsp/Index.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour.

You can't run JSP as static HTML. You need a container, that's why you could access your project well using Tomcat.

Check Oracle docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-137059.html